# Zend get nad set back UnfilteredValues

Tags: php, zend-framework

I go filter and validation set up in my form, also a use `$form->populate` to put back `$data` back to my form when fail validation but it is not working.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if(!$searchForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
        {
         $searchForm->populate($searchForm->getUnfilteredValues());
         $this->view->searchForm = $searchForm;
        }
```

when I run this I get `filteredValues` in my search field instead `UnfilteredValues`.
What I going wrong?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not apply the negation `!$searchForm->isValid($searchForm->getValues()`, because the `isValid` method actually populate the form for you,

Your code should look like:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if($searchForm->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
        {
           // do insert, upload or others
        }
}
```

As i said before, the `isValid` method actually populate form in case of invalidation of the form.

Best regards!

Comment: `if($searchForm->isValid($searchForm->getValues()))` should be `if($searchForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))`. You can't get values from the form before you've populated them.

Comment: On this form I got filter: 
`class Application_Form_Search extends Zend_Form
{
function funcName($v) {
    return preg_replace(array('/[^\d\)\(\.\s]/','[\--]','[\---]','[\----]','[\ -]','[\- ]','[\(-]','[-\)]','[^-]','[\(\)]','[-$]'),array('-','-','-','-','-','-','(',')','','','',''), $v);
}
 public function init()
    {
'filters'    => array(
                      array('StringTrim'),
                           array('callback', array('callback' => array($this, 'funcName')))
}
}`
This filter clear $data and is not mater if I use **getUnfilteredValues()** or **getValues()** got same effect.

Comment: If i understand corectly, you want in your form the ufiltered values, if that is what you want you should not populate the form inside the `isValid` method . That's all